# How to merge two DataFrames into single matching the column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two DataFrames have matching values stored in their corresponding 'names' and 'flights' columns.
While the first DataFrame stores the distances the other stores the dates:

```
import pandas as pd   

distances = {'names': ['A', 'B','C'] ,'distances':[100, 200, 300]}
dates = {'flights': ['C', 'B', 'A'] ,'dates':['1/1/16', '1/2/16', '1/3/16']}

distancesDF = pd.DataFrame(distances)
datesDF = pd.DataFrame(dates)
```

distancesDF:

```
   distances    names
0        100        A
1        200        B
2        300        C
```

datesDF:

```
    dates  flights
0  1/1/16        A
1  1/2/16        B
2  1/3/16        C
```

I would like to merge them into single Dataframe in a such a way that the matching entities are synced with the corresponding distances and dates. So the resulted DataFame would look like this:

resultDF:

```
   distances    names     dates 
0        100        A    1/1/16 
1        200        B    1/2/16 
2        300        C    1/3/16
```

What would be the way of accomplishing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that ties these dataframes together other than the positional index.  You can accomplish your desired example output with `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([distancesDF, datesDF.dates], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

To address the edit and @kartik's comment

if we create the dfs to match what's displayed.

```
distances = {'names': ['A', 'B','C'] ,'distances':[100, 200, 300]}
dates = {'flights': ['A', 'B', 'C'] ,'dates':['1/1/16', '1/2/16', '1/3/16']}

distancesDF = pd.DataFrame(distances)
datesDF = pd.DataFrame(dates)
```

then the following two options produce the same and probably desired result.

***merge***

```
 distancesDF.merge(datesDF, left_on='names', right_on='flights')[['distances', 'names', 'dates']]
```

***join***

```
distancesDF.join(datesDF.set_index('flights'), on='names')
```

both produce

[image]

Comment: Great solution. Short and simple! Thanks!

Comment: Hey! But is the `names` column not the same as the `flights` column? I would rather do a `merge`, than a `concat`...

Comment: Kartik, Please post your solution using `merge`.

Comment: @Kartik notice the dfs don't tie out with what's printed. Also notice my comments how nothing ties the dfs together. Now that the dfs look like name and flight are intended to be aligned, merge would be appropriate. My answer was correct for content present when I answered

Comment: Thanks! Great insights!